# Building timeline using Excel Table?

Tags: excel, calendar, spreadsheet

I'm trying to build a kind of timeline based on a table in Excel. The table has several columns that represent a due date. Column A is considered the key/identifier, Column B is a company name, Columns C through H are the task due dates.

My goal is to hopefully find a way to setup a second type of table that will automatically set the items in order of what key is due when. I've included an img of the table and what I'm hoping the end result would be. I haven't been able to find anything that does this. I was thinking maybe a pivot table but it's not doing what I want.

I'm not even sure if this is possible or not but any help or push in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated!

[image: Current Table]

[image: Hopeful Outcome]

Thanks!!
-Deke

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with Power Query. Just load the table, sort on date, and select which columns you want